# White div footer on page extend , how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a white `div` that extends from point (A) to point (B) on the page as shown in the photo. I want it so that when the page is extended the white takes up from pooint (A) all the way down to the end of browser so that no bg grey is shown underneath, even when page extended from below.

[image]

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talkinng about making the footer stick to the bottom of the page, Ryan Fait has a well known solution to this that you can find here:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/
Basically how it works is you position the footer absolutely and put it at the bottom, and add a "push" element to the bottom of the page to make sure that the footer doesn't go ontop of the content.

Comment: No not looking to make it stick to where when scrolls it sticks to bottom, simply just so when the browser is extended the part thats grey in the photo is white. The rest of the body is that grey tile color, but I want the footer part to be white, even when browser page is extended. Cause I can simply add a div in now that extends from A down...but specifying the height is the problem because resolutions can be crazy high and then they'd see grey if it's not extended all the way

Comment: Well, one way to do it is to simply set the background of the page to "white" and make the grey part as the background for the content - that is of course considering that all your content is in a wrapper element

Comment: Well the background of the body is currently the grey image you see now, and the div will be inside the body in a div container with the ID of footer. so not sure how that would work, I can set the div background to white but then once the page is expanded the grey will show below the white footer...which is what I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

if youre looking for the sticky footer, kpsuperplane's answer wouuld be it
But seems to me that you want to have a DIV that is bellow your content, and stretching to the bottom of your browser?.

If this is the case check this example I made really quick where I'm stretching
the bottom div to fill that area which is the result of the browsers height - the top area. Gets executed every time you resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/99FpT/

js

```
$(function() {
    function stretch(){
        $(".area2").css({"height" : $(window).height() - $(".area1").height() });
    }
    $(window).on("resize", function(){
        stretch();
    });
    stretch();
});
```

Comment: Hrm, seems to work for some of my pages, but on the main page it's seeming to make my footer a height of like 600+px.

Comment: I would have to see your code to see what other things are affecting it. Basically this example assumes you only have one area above and one bellow, so if you have any other elements you would probably need to check your css, to see if you have anything that might cause a div to not have a height defined.

Comment: If your able to take a look it's live here: http://alturl.com/u8k84 (As you can see in firebug that it's setting the bottom width for only that page to be huge, as the other pages seem fine?)

Comment: It appears everytime I resize the window it throws an inline  css of element {height: 625px;} ... when I uncheck it in firebug the height is how the other pages like it should be. But on extension agaain it does the same thing, only for that index page.

Comment: I see, yeah your div above doesn't have a height defined because you have "absolute" position elements inside , (read on block formating context). So thats why it doesn't calculate the height correctly.But aside from that, seems like you're just trying to have a clear area for people that have a larger screen right?, if thats the case you don't need to do all of that. You can just define a color bellow your background div and everytime someone stretches it'll show that bellow.